# Implementing interfaces with caching

Tags: c#, interface

In the following example code, I have an interface `IService`, that only has one method `GetDescriptors` that users need to implement.

I have also added helper methods for common queries to make working with `IService` easier. I have shown this in two different ways, methods on the interface itself, and then also via extension methods.

Whilst this works, imagine that for whatever reason, `GetDescriptorsByGroup` was actually an expensive call to make, and rather than compute its value each time its called, we'd like to lazily evaluate it and cache the result to return in future calls (the result never changes).

Is there any way this can be achieved without having to implement `GetDescriptorsByGroup` on each class implementing `IService`?

I have many classes implementing `IService`, including Mocks, so having to implement the duplicate code for `GetDescriptorsByGroup` would be less than ideal. I had thought about a baseclass, ..but then that wouldn't work for mocks.

```
public class Descriptor
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Group { get; }
    public int Count { get; }
    public string[] Dependencies { get; }

    public Descriptor(string name, string group, int count, string[] dependencies)
    {
        Name = name;
        Group = group;
        Count = count;
        Dependencies = dependencies;
    }
}

public interface IService
{
    IReadOnlyList<Descriptor> GetDescriptors();

    // helpers
    IEnumerable<Descriptor> GetDescriptorsByName(string name) => GetDescriptors().Where(e => e.Name == name);
    IEnumerable<Descriptor> GetDescriptorsByGroup(string group) => GetDescriptors().Where(e => e.Group == group);
}

// more helpers
public static class IServiceExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<Descriptor> GetDescriptorsCount(this IService service, int count) => service.GetDescriptors().Where(e => e.Count == count);
    public static IEnumerable<string> GetAllDependencies(this IService service) => service.GetDescriptors().SelectMany(e => e.Dependencies);
}

public class ServiceA : IService
{
    private readonly List<Descriptor> _descriptors;

    public ServiceA()
    {
        // compute descriptors here ...
        _descriptors = new List<Descriptor>();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Descriptor> GetDescriptors() => _descriptors;
}

public class ServiceB : IService
{
    private readonly List<Descriptor> _descriptors;

    public ServiceB()
    {
        // compute descriptors here ...
        _descriptors = new List<Descriptor>();
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Descriptor> GetDescriptors() => _descriptors;
}


internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IService service = new ServiceA();

        var x = service.GetDescriptorsByName("A");
        var y = service.GetAllDependencies();
    }
}
```

Comment: This screams ["Decorator Pattern"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern) ..., there are also libraries that make it easy to decorate through DependencyInjection ...

Comment: Interfaces cannot have instance fields, the problem is where you cache the result.

Comment: But there are concrete Services, @shingo? You can wrap them, no? Am I missing something?

Comment: What is your usage? Can you not add another layer (i.e. an aggregating singleton service) where you would cache the results, instead of adding default implementation on interfaces? It seems natural as the `IService` interface will be more focused instead of exposing convenience methods over the existing ones - Is the `GetDescriptors` method actually used elsewhere?

Comment: @Fildor I just threw a fundamental question to the OP: where should the results be cached? You cached them in the wrapper, and I think there should be other solutions besides that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you can do is a Decorator:

```
public sealed class CachingService : IService
{
    private readonly IService _valueSource;
    private readonly SomeCacheImpl<object key, Lazy<IReadOnlyList<Descriptor>>> _cache;
    private readonly object _key = new(); // In this case, there is only one key...

    public CachingService(IService valueSource)
    {
        _valueSource = valueSource;
        _cache = new(); // Or inject ...
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<Descriptor> GetDescriptors()
      => _cache.GetOrAdd(_key, _key => new Lazy<IReadOnlyList<Descriptor>>(() => _valueSource.GetDescriptors()).Value;
}
```

That you then can inject instead of the concrete IService implementation:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IService service = new CachingService(new ServiceA());

    var x = service.GetDescriptorsByName("A");
    var y = service.GetAllDependencies();
}
```

Comment: But this introduces its own set of problems if a service already had a base class

Comment: Why would it? This implements IService. It does not inherit any ServiceX classes. Thus, you can "cachify" anything that implements IService. @Vastar

Comment: If I have  `class ServiceA : IServiceA, IService`, and I create a `new CachingService(serviceA)`, then I can't pass that instance to things expecting a 'ServiceA' anymore.

Comment: Well, that's a design issue you didn't include in the question. Let me try something and come back to this ... can you edit the question to include an example, of what we would have to expect from such an `IServiceA`?

Comment: @Vastar small note (I personally like to use this pattern too and was bit by this several times) - this has a chance to cache error/exception (if the factory will throw the exception)

Comment: ^^ Absolutely, you should add the appropriate amount of Exception Handling you need to any solution to any problem you find on SO.